# Know if app downloaded from a website

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I am implementing deep linking. On our website, the app download banner is there. If a user clicks on download button and the app is downloaded. Is there a way to know that this app was downloaded after redirecting too appstore from our website or user directly went to app store, searched for the app and downloaded.

Comment: This has nothing to do with deep linking. You can create campaign links in AppAnalytics inside [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and put these on your website.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is 'attribution', not 'deep linking'. ***Deferred*** deep linking might be involved if you want to send users directly to a specific place in your app after they download by clicking on the banner button, but tracking who downloaded is a separate problem.

iTunes Connect [campaign links](http://help.apple.com/itc/appanalytics/#/itc571d39765) track this to a certain extent, but [they are often found to be unreliable](https://mobilegrowthstack.com/https-mobilegrowthstack-com-how-to-implement-the-mobile-growth-stack-fdb5c57a98f1). You'll probably want a third-party install attribution tool like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) or Firebase Dynamic Links. Branch actually has an [out-of-the-box smart banner option](https://branch.io/smart-app-banner/).

If you're doing a lot of paid ads, you might also want to investigate ad attribution providers like Adjust, Tune, or AppsFlyer.